# Maven: How do I deploy my WAR file to a remote Tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, maven, maven-2

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I want to deploy my WAR file to a remote Tomcat 6 server, running the Tomcat manager app, in the verify phase of my project.  How can I do that?  I thought the Cargo plugin was the key to salvation but when I added this to my pom.xml file ...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat${tomcat.major}x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${tomcat.major}/v${tomcat.version}/bin/apache-tomcat-${tomcat.version}.tar.gz</url>
                        <downloadDir>${project.build.directory}/downloads</downloadDir>
                        <extractDir>${project.build.directory}/extracts</extractDir>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/tomcat${tomcat.major}x.log</output>
                    <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo.log</log>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <home>${project.build.directory}/tomcat-${tomcat.version}/container</home>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>${tomcat.servlet.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                        <cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>${tomcat.ajb.port}</cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <deployer>
                            <deployables>
                                <deployable>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <type>war</type>
                                    <pingURL>http://localhost:${tomcat.servlet.port}/${project.artifactId}</pingURL>
                                    <pingTimeout>30000</pingTimeout>
                                    <properties>
                                        <context>${project.artifactId}</context>
                                    </properties>
                                </deployable>
                            </deployables>
                        </deployer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!--  In the verify phase, deploy the app to a Tomcat instance.  We
                      require that the properties "tomcat.manager.url", "tomcat.username", and
                      "tomcat.password" be defined. 
                 -->
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-to-remote-tomcat</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>tomcat${tomcat.major}x</containerId>
                            <type>remote</type>
                        </container>
                        <configuration>
                            <type>runtime</type>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>${tomcat.manager.url}</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                                <cargo.remote.username>${tomcat.username}</cargo.remote.username>
                                <cargo.remote.password>${tomcat.password}</cargo.remote.password>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <deployer>
                            <type>remote</type>
                            <deployables>
                                <deployable>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                                </deployable>
                            </deployables>
                        </deployer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution> 
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I get the error

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.1.3:redeploy (deploy-to-remote-tomcat) on project myco-productplus-web: Execution deploy-to-remote-tomcat of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.1.3:redeploy failed: Failed to create deployer with implementation class org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat6xRemoteDeployer for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat6x]], deployer type [remote]). argument type mismatch -> [Help 1]
```

Thanks for any suggestions, - Dave

Comment: Based on your configuration you have downloaded and started a Tomcat and deployed your war archive into that Tomcat (pre-integration-test) furthermore you are trying to deploy your war into a remote tomcat (verify).  Does there exist a good reason for that?. If you call mvn verify the pre-integration-test, integration-test, verify are the phases which are running in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [these instructions](http://www.wakaleo.com/component/content/article/244) and based on your error message, try removing the `<type>remote</type>` element under the `<deployer>` tag and try again.

Comment: I removed the "<type>remote</type>" per your suggestion.  While that did make the error go away, the WAR file didn't get deployed to the Tomcat server, even though running "mvn clean verify" with the appropriate properties (e.g. -Dtomcat.manager.url=) resulted in success.  What's weirder, when I intentionally put in a bad tomcat manager URL or password, I still got a build success.

Comment: Btw, I went ahead and accepted since it seems like my problem is multiple configurations, but if you have any other thoughts, definitely respond in comments.  Thanks, -