# How to install Tomcat6 manager application

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, tomcat6

I

- installed Tomcat6 on EC2 micro-instance,
- then added to `tomcat-users.xml` following line: `<user name="tomcat-admin" password="mypassword" roles="manager,admin" />` and
- finally tried to access the manager application at `http://myhost:8080/manager`.

This didn't work - I got the `404` error message. `http://myhost:8080/manager/html` doesn't work, either.

Then I looked into the directory `var/lib/tomcat6/webapps` and found no `manager` directory there (see below).

[image]

What is the correct way to install the Tomcat6 manager application in EC2 linux?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing Tomcat 6 and installing Tomcat 7 according to [this tutorial](http://in4ray.blogspot.ru/2012/04/install-tomcat-7-on-amazon-linux.html) using following command line statement:

`sudo yum install tomcat7-webapps tomcat7-docs-webapp tomcat7-admin-webapps`

Comment: Thanks! this helped me, however,in CentOS 7.0 what worked for me was:
sudo yum install tomcat-webapps tomcat-docs-webapp tomcat-admin-webapps

Answer (score 2):

Just download Tomcat (zip version) and upload the manager directory to your servers webapp directory. It only contains jsp so there is no need for an installation. Btw: If you are looking for a really great tomcat manager tool you can check [PsiProbe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/).

Comment: Thanks. I need the manager application in order to implement continuous deployment (as described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922311/how-to-implement-continous-deployment-for-a-web-service ). Does PsiProbe do it better (easier, faster...) than the standard manager app?